# Equation causes overfull hbox

Tags: xetex, equations, paragraphs

I have the following code, which causes an overfull line. I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
    For the example shown in Figure~2, assuming $c_1=$ \emph{BiasFieldCorrector} and $c_2=$ \emph{Cerebro}, initially $\operatorname{prop}\{c_{11}\}=\{$\emph{SkullStrippedImage}$\}$ where $c_{11} \in \operatorname{Input}\{c_1\}$. After forward propagation, $\operatorname{prop}\{c_{22}\}=\{\textit{SkullStrippedImage}\}$ where $c_{22} \in \operatorname{Output}\{c_{2}\}$, propagating the semantic properties forward.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `$c=$ foo` as if `=` is not used in infix position it will get the wrong spacing if you must mix math and text then `$c={}$foo`  will ensure that you get mathrel spacing on both sides of the `=` but here `\emph` seems logically wrong (you want italic not emphasis) so I used `c=\mathit{foo}`. However the text simply doesn't fit.  You could re-write to make it fit, but I won't attempt that as I'm not sure enough of the meaning Or probably better for such "lumpy" text do not try to justify the right margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}\raggedright
    For the example shown in Figure~2, assuming $c_1= \mathit{BiasFieldCorrector}$ and $c_2= \mathit{Cerebro}$, initially $\operatorname{prop}\{c_{11}\}=\{\mathit{kullStrippedImage}\}$ where $c_{11} \in \operatorname{Input}\{c_1\}$. After forward propagation, $\operatorname{prop}\{c_{22}\}=\{\mathit{SkullStrippedImage}\}$ where $c_{22} \in \operatorname{Output}\{c_{2}\}$, propagating the semantic properties forward.
\end{document}
```

Or with indentation restored as mentioned in comments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

{\raggedright\parindent=15pt 
    For the example shown in Figure~2, assuming $c_1= \mathit{BiasFieldCorrector}$ and $c_2= \mathit{Cerebro}$, initially $\operatorname{prop}\{c_{11}\}=\{\mathit{kullStrippedImage}\}$ where $c_{11} \in \operatorname{Input}\{c_1\}$. After forward propagation, $\operatorname{prop}\{c_{22}\}=\{\mathit{SkullStrippedImage}\}$ where $c_{22} \in \operatorname{Output}\{c_{2}\}$, propagating the semantic properties forward.\par}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `mathit` seems wrong to me here since it seems to treat each character as a separate variable. Wouldn't `textit` be more proper?

Comment: No `\mathit` is _not_ the math italic font (which has wide sidebearings to separate letters as you describe) it is the font for italic multi-letter identifiers in math mode (which is usually the same font as the text italic (but a lot more efficient to access)

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for that correction. On a side note, how do I access the math italic font then?

Comment: `$abc$` is math italic `$\mathit{abc}$` is text-italic-as-a-math-font If you need to explicitly select the math italic it's `\mathnormal` (but I don't think I've ever used that)

Comment: Ok so I wanted the indentation for the paragraph back so I did `\parindent=15pt` after `\raggedright`, and now the margin alignment is screwed up again.

Comment: @KG I get no overfull lines if I put the parindent as you suggest, see updated answer.

Comment: The spacing in `\mathit` looks wrong for text, and I’m almost certain that with `unicode-math` it uses the math italic alphabet not the italic text font.

Comment: @KhaledHosny looking at the image seems you are right, but that's a bug in unicode-math: \mathit is supposed to be a text font.

Comment: Ok so it's the `\par` at the end you've added. Try your example without it. The text is misaligned then. Can you explain why that happens?

Comment: @KG baseline and alignment settings (`\large`, `raggedright`, etc) are _paragraph_ settings: a paragraph is set using the values in force at the end of the paragraph, so if the group ends before the paragraph the paragraph is set with the values in force before the group.